# Import dotenv in Meteor 1.8

Tags: meteor, environment-variables, dotenv

This is probably a stupid mistake but I've already spent hours on it so any help would be appreciated.

I created a meteor 1.8.3 app with `meteor create example`. I ran `npm i dotenv --save-dev`. `dotenv` got installed into `node_modules`.

Edited `server/main.js` like so:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  dotenv.config();
});
```

This gives me a `TypeError: dotenv.config is not a function`. `console.log(dotenv)` returns an empty object `{}`. Any idea why?

Comment: I had this problem but when I turned off my application and started it again. It worked! so maybe some caching issue related to node_modules? Anyway, here's my repo: https://github.com/harryadelb/meteor-dotenv-example

Comment: I did look at your repo and it does work on my machine. However, no clue what the difference is between yours and mine.

Comment: Try `rm -rf node_modules` and reinstall everything again, then give it a go.

Comment: Also, while a bit out of context Meteor.settings is designed to help you out with environment variables.

Comment: apparently the fact that I saved dotenv as a devDependency posed a problem. No clue why...

Comment: huh, that's weird!

Comment: It does not exactly answer to the question, but do you know you can use `Meteor.settings` for environment variables? have a look at this: https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-settings

Answer (score 0):

When developing using Meteor it's very common that commands creating a change into `node_modules` (like `npm install`) are not taken into account while the application is running. You need to stop it and run it again to take into account the updated `node_modules`.

To avoid this behavior, use the `npm` version bundled with the `meteor` cli instead of the one you installed :

```
meteor npm install --save-dev dotenv
```

Comment: Meteor was not running when I installed the npm packages.